# migrate from react-native Navigator to React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to build a simple app from a tutorial I'm watching.

This tutorial is about 5 months old now and uses the old React Navigator method of Navigation as seen in the code below.

So I tried using the new React Navigation library, but I can't find any way to get the code below to fit into the new React Navgation method. In fact, I don't really know where to start.  I read through the intro docs at reactnavigation.org, but it's kind of overwhelming.

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

```
  <Navigator
    ref = {( ref ) => this._navigator = ref }
    configureScene = { this.configureScene.bind( this )}
    renderScene = { this.renderScene.bind( this )}
  />


 renderScene(route, navigator) {
   switch(route) {
     default: {
       return null;
     }
   }
 }
 configureScene(route, routeStack) {
   return Navigator.SceneConfig.PushFromRight;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, add your import :

```
import {
  StackNavigator
} from 'react-navigation';
```

Let s say that your app contains two screens, screen_1 & screen_2

(this code is not tested, debug if any compilation error arises)

```
class Screen_1 extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View flex={1} justifyContent="center" alignItems="center" >
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.navigateToNextScreen.bind(this)}>
                    <Text>Screen 1</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            )
    }

    navigateToNextScreen(){
        this.props.navigation.navigate("SecondScreen")
        // notice that the "SecondScreen" is the name of the component 
        // Screen_1 in the AppStack
    }
}

class Screen_2 extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <View flex={1} justifyContent="center" alignItems="center">
                <Text>Screen 2</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

you create a stackNavigator Component as follows :

```
const AppStack = StackNavigator({
    FirstScreen : {
        screen : Screen_1,
        navigationOptions : {
            title : 'Screen 1'
        }
    },
    SecondScreen : {
        screen : Screen_2,
        navigationOptions : {
            title : 'Screen 2'
        }
    }
})
```

Then you can use the AppStack as any other component.

I can even believe that you can use it in the renderScene of your react-native Navigator as follows:

```
renderScene(route, navigator) {
   switch(route) {
     default: {
       return (<AppStack />);
     }
   }
 }
```

I'd really advise you this [youtube tutorial,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C96piR3FRww) it got me up and running in less than twenty minutes.